# Mask UIView with UIBezierPath - Stroke Only

Tags: ios, swift

*Update 02 has a working solution...*

I am trying to use the stroke of a UIBezierPath as a mask on another UIView. There are many examples, but they all use the fill to clip views.

I'm trying to use only the stroke of the path, but it's not displaying correctly.

Below is what I currently have in Swift 3.x:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100))
bezierPath.lineWidth = 5.0
bezierPath.stroke()

let gradient = Gradient(frame: self.bounds)
let mask = CAShapeLayer()

mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
gradient.layer.mask = mask

self.addSubview(gradient)
```

But, the above code does this. I'm looking for only to use the stroke for the mask... This is what the code is currently doing

[image: Currently doing..]

This is the desired outcome.. 
[image: Desired outcome]

(has more points in this comp snapshot)

I realize that there might be a better way, open to any ideas or alternatives!

---

***--Update 01--***

My latest, but masks out everything:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100))
bezierPath.lineWidth = 5.0
bezierPath.stroke()

let gradient = Gradient(frame: self.bounds)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: gradient.bounds.width, height: gradient.bounds.height))
let context : CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
gradient.layer.mask?.contents = image?.cgImage
```

And.. got nowhere after trying to figure it out with CAShapeLayer:

```
let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
mask.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
mask.fillRule = kCAFillModeBoth
mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
gradient.layer.mask = mask
self.addSubview(gradient)
```

---

***--Update 02 - Working Solution --***

Thanks for everybody's help!

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 200))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 100))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 200))

let gradient = Gradient(frame: self.bounds) // subclass of UIView

let mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.fillColor = nil
mask.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
mask.lineWidth = 5.0
gradient.layer.mask = mask

self.addSubview(gradient)
```

And, the results are what I was wanting:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: You are not telling where you are using your code.

Comment: Encapsulated in a subclass of UIView

Comment: You might have to render the stroked path into an UIImage then use the UIImage as the mask.

Comment: That's a good idea @ekscrypto

Comment: 1. You say you only want the stroke of the path.  But you are not setting the stroke color.  2. Do you need the following line?  gradient.layer.mask = mask

Comment: @ElTomato 1. UIBezierPath does not have a stroke color property, only a CGBlendMode and Alpha. So, I cannot color the path.. 2. Yes, I'm trying to "reveal" the gradient view of the area the UIBezier path – good questions too

Comment: No, UIBezierPath doesn't.  But CAShapeLayer does.

Comment: @ElTomato I tried setting the .fillColor, .strokeColor, and .fillRule of the CAShapeLayer and it rendered the same as before.. Excellent feedback!

Comment: Any progress with your issue?

Comment: @ekscrypto, thanks for checking up. But, not really.. I've been trying wrap my head around rendering the stroke only into a UIImage --- I'll update my question with my latest

Comment: I don't understand the question. What can it mean to use a stroke as a mask? Can you explain/draw the effect you're trying to produce?

Comment: @matt, okay added a snapshot of what I am looking to achieve..

Comment: @August , i tried to completely explain this confusing issue in an answer below.  Hope it helps you or someone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `UIBezierPath` has several properties that only matter when stroking the path, including `lineWidth`, `lineCapStyle`, `lineJoinStyle`, and `miterLimit`.

A `CGPath` has none of these properties.

Thus when you set `mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath`, none of the stroke properties you set on `bezierPath` carries over. You've extracted just the `CGPath` from the `UIBezierPath` and none of those other properties.

You need to set the stroking properties on the `CAShapeLayer` rather than on any path object. Thus:

```
mask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
mask.lineWidth = 5
```

You also need to set a stroke color, because the default stroke color is nil, which means don't stroke at all:

```
mask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

And, because you **don't** want the shape layer to fill the path, you need to set the fill color to nil:

```
mask.fillColor = nil
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This did the trick... I'll update my question with the working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly how to do it

## with detailed discussion and explanation:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    setup()
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

private lazy var layerToUseAsAMask: CAShapeLayer = {
    let l = CAShapeLayer()

    // Recall that often you'd just draw the path here, but, somewhat confusingly
    // we will draw the path in layout, since, we do need to know the sizes to
    // draw the path

    l.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    l.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    l.lineWidth = thick
    l.lineCap = .round

    // So, the bezier path is going to be on this layer. recall that (confusingly)
    // it's the >layer<, not the path, which has the line qualities. The bezier
    // path is a 100% platonic path!

    // Recall too that overall, >all< of this is merely the CAShapeLayer, which
    // will be >used as a mask< on our actual layer of interest ("ourLayer")

    return l
}()

private lazy var ourLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
    let l = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.addSublayer(l)
    l.frame = self.bounds
    l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    l.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]

    // Recall that to round an image layer (or gradient later) you use the .mask
    // facility (>not< a path)

    l.mask = layerToUseAsAMask

    // Recall too that, somewhat bizarrely really, changes at layout to a path
    // push up to a layer (in our case our maskToUseAsMask); and indeed changes
    // to a .mask facility (in our case, the one on our main layer) push up
    // to a layer (ie, in our case to our main layer).

    return l
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    common()
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

func common() {

    ourLayer.frame = bounds

    layerToUseAsAMask.frame = bounds

    // Recall as explained above, every single time we layout, you have to
    // actually draw the path again.  It is "pushed up" to maskToUseAsMask
    // and ultimately to the .mask on our ourLayer.

    let pBar = UIBezierPath()
    pBar.move(to: ...)
    pBar.addLine(to: ...)
    maskToUseAsMask.path = pBar.cgPath

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.20
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
}
```

In iOS a mask has been named by Apple .. a layer!  Hence a "CAShapeLayer" can be a layer (a layer of an image), or in a totally different usage it can be ... a mask.

```
let someMaskIAmAMaking = CAMask() ... no! 

let someMaskIAmAMaking = CAShapeLayer() ... strange but true. Bad Apple.
```

Always bear in mind that in iOS, "CAMask" does not exist - you use "CALayer" for both "CAMask" and "CALayer".

To shape a custom layer you have added (whether a gradient, photo of a cat, or anything else) you need to use a mask.  That's a mask .. ***not a path***.

We're going to be shaping a layer, so we'll use a mask. (And that means - WTF - a CAShapeLayer.)

```
let ourMask = CAShapeLayer( ...
```

Hence.

## 1. Make a layer, the only purpose of which is to use as a mask

Recall that often you'd just draw the path here, but, somewhat confusingly
we will draw the path in layout, since, we do need to know the sizes to
     draw the path.

So, the bezier path is going to be on this layer. recall that (confusingly)
it's the >layer<, not the path, which has the line qualities. the bezier
path is a 100% platonic path!

Recall too that overall, >all< of this is merely the CAShapeLayer, which
will be >used as a mask< on our actual layer of interest ("ourLayer")

## 2. Make your actual new special layer (here, a gradient)

Recall that to round an image layer (or gradient later) you use the .mask
facility (>not< a path)

Recall too that, somewhat bizarrely really, changes at layout to a path
     push up to a layer (in our case our maskToUseAsMask); and indeed changes
    to a .mask facility (in our case, the one on our ourLayer) push up
 to a layer (ie, in our case to our ourLayer).

## 3. At layout times, actually draw the path

Recall as explained above, every single time we layout, you have to
actually draw the path again.  It is "pushed up" to maskToUseAsMask
and ultimately to the .mask on our ourLayer.

## 4. Finally set an ordinary shadow "on the view"

So,

```
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.20 etc ...
```

Recall that the shadow "on the view" is the one built-in to ".layer", the "main and basic layer" of the view.  You simply turn that on by setting the .shadowOpacity of .layer to a value.

That is quite different from adding a shadow ***on some other layer you have added***.  To add a shadow ***on some other layer you have added***, such as catLayer, you use catLayer.path.  (That procedure, which is totally different, is explained here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465440/294884 )

Comment: Great stuff, hope to be able to use it soon! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to draw a bezierPath into an image, then use the resulting image as a mask.  The issue with your code is that while you add the bezier path to the context, you never stroke() it.  I would like to refer you to this swift function which can draw an array of paths into an image:  [Create an UIImage from Uibezierpath Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451491/create-an-uiimage-from-uibezierpath-array-in-swift)

You can confirm the image renders properly by displaying it into a UIImageView.  Once you have confirmed that, should be rather easy to use as mask: [iOS layer mask from UIImage/CGImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004148/ios-layer-mask-from-uiimage-cgimage)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help, man.. I was able to render the path in the image, but couldn't wrap my head around the masking.. Great ideas and links!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly in Core Graphics without using `CALayer` classes, which is useful if you're drawing into an image.

You need to first convert the bezier path into a "stroked" version of itself, then clip and fill the resulting path with your gradient.

I use these wrapper functions:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    
    // Return a path that represents the outline of the receiver when stroked
    public func strokedPath() -> UIBezierPath?
    {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        
        ctx.addPath(self.cgPath)
        ctx.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth)
        ctx.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
        
        guard let path = ctx.path  else { return nil }
        return UIBezierPath(cgPath: path)
    }
    
    /// Fills the receiving bezier path with a gradient
    public func fillWithLinearGradient(start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint, colors:[UIColor], fractions:[CGFloat]? = nil)
    {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        ctx.saveGState()
        defer { ctx.restoreGState() } // clean up graphics state changes when the method returns
        
        self.addClip() // use the path as the clipping region
        
        let cgColors = colors.map({ $0.cgColor })
        let locations = (fractions?.count == colors.count) ? fractions : nil
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: cgColors as CFArray, locations: locations) else { return }
        
        ctx.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: start, end: end, options: [])
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
myBezierPath.strokedPath()?.fillWithLinearGradient(start: /* ... */)
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing this! I hope to try it out one day soon :-)